# Est-il correct de parler de « couronnement » quand je vais chez le dentiste?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire

Est-ce que je peux dire que je vais « me faire couronner » ou que je vais à « mon couronnement » quand je vais chez le dentiste pour qu'il me pose une couronne sur une dent ?

Ou bien faut-il utiliser une autre expression ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Employer ces expressions me semble être un jeu de mots, voire une maladresse de langage.

Je propose tout simplement:

> me faire placer (ou poser) une couronne (sur la dent)

Answer (score 7):

Techniquement, ce serait plutôt ta dent qui va à son couronnement. Mais par métonymie, je pense qu'on peut considérer cet usage approprié, même s'il sonne un peu étrangement, ne serait-ce que par humour ou poésie.

**En résumé : si tu veux être clair, c'est une mauvaise expression. Si tu veux être (original/poétique/décalé/taquin)* c'est une jolie idée.**

(* rayez la ou les mentions éventuellement inutiles)

Answer (score 4):

La solution la plus simple? préciser qui portera le joyau :

> Je vais me faire couronner *une dent*.

Sans cette précision il faut beaucoup de malice et d'humour pour faire entendre de quoi l'on parle, sinon on peut se faire répondre : « Tu te prends pour la reine (ou le roi) d'Angleterre ? »

Le couronnement étant une cérémonie, sinon un sacre,

> Je vais à mon couronnement.

ne passera pas, à moins qu'il y ait connivence sur ce sujet entre les personnes.

Tenter peut-être « je vais assister à un couronnement »… sur un ton badin et en situation.

Comment: (+1) Ta première proposition me semble a posteriori la meilleure qu'on puisse substituer ici. Bien vu !